# Validate complex types with DataAnnotations

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, data-annotations

I've decided to use Entity Framework for O/R Mapping, and DataAnnotations for validation in my project, and I have now encountered an odd problem when trying to implement this.

This is what I've done:

I have the following entity type

```
Contact
*******
Int32 Id (not null, Entity Key)
Name Name (not null) 
Address Address (not null)
String Phone
String Email
```

where `Name` and `Address` are complex types defined as follows:

```
Name                                  Address
****                                  *******
String First (not null)               String Street (not null)
String Last (not null)                String ZipCode (not null)
                                      String City (not null)
```

And the following classes reside in the same namespace as my entities:

```
public class ContactMetadata
{
    [Required]
    public Name Name { get; set; }
}

[MetadataType(typeof(ContactMetadata))]
partial class Contact { }
```

However, when I create a new `Contact` item, the `Name` and `Address` types are filled with instances of `Name` and `Address` where all values are `null`, instead of `Name` and `Address` having `null` values themselves. Thus, the `Required` attribute doesn't throw any errors, although all values are `null`. How do I work around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it creates instances of the Name and Address objects who's properties are null?  Interesting.

Can you just put the [Required] attribute on the children?

EDIT: I know this might be considered a smelly way of doing this, but for clarity I edit your answer into the post, so that it can easier be found by the next person having problems with this...

**Suggested** (and accepted, but yet untested) **solution:**

Write a custom validation attribute which validates against the `null` values.

Comment: Exactly. I created a new class named NameMetadata, using the same structure as above, and set both First and Last names required, but it made no difference.

Comment: There's a bounty on this question now - and you're the one closest to get anywhere... ;)

Comment: Oh, how sad, I have no idea.  Have you maybe tried making a custom attribute and validating against the null value in there?

Comment: No, I haven't. But, given that it's done correctly, that will probably work... thanks! =)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the names that end up in the HTML fields line up with the property names of the class.

For example, if you have this:

```
public class Contact {
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; }
}

public class Address {
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    [...]
}
```

Your calls to the HTML helpers should look like this:

```
<%= Html.TextBox("FirstName") %>
<%= Html.TextBox("LastName") %>
<%= Html.TextBox("Address.Street") %>
<%= Html.TextBox("Address.City") %>
[...]
```

Comment: I haven't gotten to the view part yet - but I will, and when I do this is useful information. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check out this blog post [complex-dataannotations-validation](http://robertfburke.blogspot.com/2009/07/complex-dataannotations-validation.html).  I think the RequiredAssociation attribute is what you need.  You might have to tweak it a little bit for Entity Framework instead of LINQ to SQL.

Answer (score 0):

I'm struggling with the same issue right now.  I think a semi-graceful way to do it is to reference the key primitive type as a property, and put the dataannotation on that.  Here's an example with AddressID being the key field.

```
public class Contact{

[Required]
public int? AddressIDForValidation{
get{return this.Address.AdressID;}
}

public Address Address{get;set;}
}



public class Address{
public int? AddressID{get;set;}
public string Street{get;set;}
}
```