# Seeking a reusable PostalCode model for MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, data-annotations, asp.net-mvc-5, dry

I have the following validation/presentation that I use on a postal code field, in a ViewModel, in my ASP.NET MVC web site. I'd like to share this implementation with 5 other postal code editors, on other models, in my application. How can I avoid duplicating this code?

```
[Required]
[RegularExpression(LocationMatch.NorthAmericanPostalCodePattern,
    ErrorMessage = "You may look up cities here, but must submit a North American postal code")]
[Display(Name = "Postal Code", Prompt = "or type city")]
[Remote("ValidatePostalCode", "Utilities")]
[CustomValidation(typeof(CandidateMobileEditor), "ValidatePostalCode")]
public string PostalCode { get; set; }

public static ValidationResult ValidatePostalCode(string postalCode) {
    return LocationMatch.Closest(postalCode) == null ?
        new ValidationResult("Postal code not found") : null;
}

public void Load(Candidate sourceProfile) {
    PrimaryPostalCode = sourceProfile.Account.FormattedPostalCode;
}

public void Save(Candidate targetProfile) {
    targetProfile.Account.FormattedPostalCode = LocationMatch.Closest(PrimaryPostalCode).PostalCode;
}
```

Additionally, I have the following JavaScript associated with each postal code field. I mention this for completeness, as I am aware of some ways to trigger this to be activated from common code, but only if I can cause a common template to load or decorate the model with some common custom attributes.

```
singletons.lac = new locationAutocomplete("input[name='PrimaryPostalCode']");

function locationAutocomplete(selector) {
    var cache = {}, lastXhr;
    var locationField = $(selector);
    locationField.autocomplete({
        minLength: 5,
        delay: 0, // note the lookup delay is increased during the first search event
        search: function (event, ui) { locationField.autocomplete("option", "delay", 300); },
        change: function (event, ui) { locationField.change(); },
        source: function (request, response) {
            var term = request.term;
            if (term in cache) {
                response(cache[term]);
                return;
            }

            lastXhr = $.getJSON(SiteContext.VirtualRoot + "Utilities/GetMatchingLocations", request, function (data, status, xhr) {
                cache[term] = data;
                if (xhr === lastXhr) {
                    response(data);
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: p.s. One possible solution I've considered is to create a shared child ViewModel with only one field. I have suspicions that will eventually give me grief with binding something at some point in the future, but it's my only current idea.

Comment: as I suspected, I tried this and it's ugly to make the postal code required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new ViewModel specifically for this postal code editor, then create a partial view to hold the required html and javascript.

when you need to use this you can include this ViewModel in your page ViewModel and use @Html.Partial("Your Postal Partial View File") to load this into your page.

Comment: How would you ensure the new viewmodel is not null? Put a 'Required' attribute on each with a reasonable validation message, and add a 'ValidationMessageFor' to the parent view?

Comment: As per this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1061561/validate-complex-types-with-dataannotations

Comment: i generally initialize the child viewmodels inside the parent viewmodels default constructor, if you have a [Required] on your child viewmodel properties then the validation will be triggered when you submit the form.

Comment: That will work. Don't get me wrong, I appreciate the answer. This sort of thing just exposes weaknesses in the platform. By the time I get done I'll have almost as much abstraction code as the code I'm abstracting.